# How to add bouncing animation for UIImageview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, caanimation

Animation not familiar for me ,but now i am like to learn it .so i googled and get spring and CAanimation ,gravity ,collition like that .

**What i was tried :**

```
-(void)longpress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longg
{


    UIGestureRecognizerState state =[longg state];
    if(state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        int temptag=[longg.view tag];
        UIImageView *views=(UIImageView *)arrimgstore[temptag];
                NSLog(@"got it to super view %@",views);
        [UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:1 usingSpringWithDamping:2 initialSpringVelocity:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

            [_imgfull bringSubviewToFront:views];
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

while bringsubviewtoFront action happens ,i like to add some attractive animation.

Above code is some thing wrong please help me to achieve this :) thanks .

Comment: What happens if it's already at the front? E.g. opacity from 0 to 1

Comment: no problem even if bounce but not getting @zcui93

Comment: use CAKeyFrameAnimation to get more control of the animation. You can do many custom animations using it.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri which one is best to do it spring ,cakeyframe,uidynamicanimator ?

Comment: For gravity kind of animations it is easy to use UIKitDynamics, and if you want to customise the animation for frame by frame....you have to use CAKeyFrameAnimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple bounce animation, you can do it using `CAKeyFrameAnimation`:

```
CAMediaTimingFunction *linearTiming = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
CAMediaTimingFunction *easeOutTiming = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

CAKeyframeAnimation *fbTranslationYAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
fbTranslationYAnimation.duration = 0.700;
fbTranslationYAnimation.values = @[@(0.000), @(-35.000), @(-55.000), @(-45.000), @(-35.000), @(-39.000), @(-43.000), @(-39.000), @(-35.000), @(-37.000), @(-35.000)];
fbTranslationYAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.143), @(0.286), @(0.429), @(0.571), @(0.643), @(0.714), @(0.786), @(0.857), @(0.929), @(1.000)];
fbTranslationYAnimation.timingFunctions = @[easeOutTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
fbTranslationYAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+delay;
fbTranslationYAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
fbTranslationYAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;
[[self.imgView layer] addAnimation:fbTranslationYAnimation forKey:@"BounceAnimation_TranslationY"];
```

This gives the effect:

[image]

For more info regarding the CoreAnimation timing, please read [this](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/)

If you want to do it using the UIKitDynamics, you can avoid so much of code. you can do it like:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize the animator.
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
}
```

and then add gravity(to fall),collision(to react when it touches other view),elasticity(to bounce) to the imageview:

```
 UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.imgView]];

[self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];

UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.imgView]];

[collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"
                                   fromPoint:self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin
                                     toPoint:CGPointMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x + self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y)];

[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *bounceBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.imgView]];
    bounceBehavior.elasticity = 0.75;
[self.animator addBehavior:bounceBehavior];
```